# Power after ignition switch

Tags: ignition, power, switches, wiring-diagram

First of all hello to everyone.

I have got a sinnis terrain 125 that I have swapped the engine, and now it won't start. I have changed the rear part of the loom, all connectors nice and clean, ecu is new.

So basically when I turn the key and press start button it don't prime the fuel pump, second the panel stays on even after turning key off.

When I disconnected the plugs from start button, the ignition turn on and off the panel as it should.

So im having power after the ignition, how can I identify where is the culprit? Can I do a straight continuity check from end to end of the harness? Or what steps should I take? The start / kill switch is new as well as i brought a  new one to check.

- Side stand disconnected ok
- Clutch switch disconnected ok
- Solenoid ok
- Battery ok
- Rear loom as it is new ok
- Fuses ok

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!